# Bolding text generated by physics package

Tags: align, bold, physics

I would like to bold parts of my equation, but it seems `\bm` is incompatible with `\pdv`, and neither `\boldsymbol` nor `\vectorbold` (also from `physics`) can bold the operators; `\boldmath` doesn't work at all. I would like to be able to bold the whole first term. I can get `\boldsymbol` to bold a little bit more if it's not in the align environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{My Example}
Differentiating $\mathcal{Q}(\bm{\tau})$ in respect to $\tau_t$:

\begin{align*}
\pdv{\mathcal{Q}(\bm{\tau})}{\tau_{t}} =   &\int_{0}^{1} \Bigg[ \alt<2>{\bm{q^*(p,\tau,w)}}{q^*(p,\tau,w)} \pdv{z^*(w)}{\tau_t} \enspace + \\
  & \int_0^{z^*(w)} \pdv{\tilde{q}}{x}\dv{x}{\tau_t} \Bigg ] \, \dif{F(z)} \dif{F(w)} 
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture]

Comment: @Sebastiano yes. I should mention that. If you replace `\bm` with it nothing bolds.

Comment: I have seen also derivative and diffcoeff packages but I have not seen that it is possibile to have bold symbols for the operator \partial. But is it important that you must necessary to use physics package?

Comment: @Sebastiano No. Defining my own commands is the backup. Although I'm concerned whatever is making it not work in their package will affect me too.

Comment: Please, can you give the green check mark to the user @Simon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to point out that you can change the font of `\partial` and `d` with the derivative package using the option `style-inf=<font>`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm} % pdflatex
%\usepackage{unicode-math} % lualatex or xelatex

\usepackage{derivative}

\derivset{\pdv}[style-inf=\bm{\partial}] % pdflatex
\derivset{\odv}[style-inf=\bm{d}]        % pdflatex
%\derivset{\pdv}[style-inf=\symbf{\partial}] % lualatex or xelatex
%\derivset{\odv}[style-inf=\symbf{d}]        % lualatex or xelatex

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \pdv{ f(x,y,z) }{ x, y, z } \quad \odv{ f(x) }{ x }
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

If you want upright bold `d`, then you should use `\derivset{\odv}[style-inf=\bm{\mathrm{d}}]`with pdflatex.

**EDIT** Updated for version 1.1.

[image]

Comment: Very good. I have not read very well the documentation. +1 surely.

Answer (score 4):

The `diffcoeff` package also allows the easy use of a bold `\partial` or `d`. You will need names for them, say `ob` for ordinary-derivative-bold, and `pb` for partial-derivative-bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{diffcoeff}
\diffdef{ob}{ op-symbol = \bm{ \mathrm{d}} }
\diffdef{pb}{ op-symbol = \bm{\partial} }
\begin{document}
\[
\diff.ob.{\mathcal{Q}(\bm{\tau})}{\tau_{t}}\qquad
\diff.pb.{\mathcal{Q}(\bm{\tau})}{\tau_{t}}
\]
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to write `\diff.ob.` and `\diff.pb.` all the time, follow the `\diffdef` commands in the preamble with

```
\newcommand{\ob}{\diff.ob.}
\newcommand{\pb}{\diff.pb.}
```

or some other names of your choosing. You can then replace the `\diff.ob.` with `\ob` and `\diff.pb.` with `\pb`. [image: bold derivative symbols]

Answer (score 3):

I will use the classic `\frac` instead of the packages `physics`, `diffcoeff`, `derivative`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
\[
  \mathcal{Q}(\bm{\tau})=\frac{{\bm\partial}z^*(w)}{{\bm\partial}\tau_t}\frac{{\bm d}x}{{\bm d}t}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]